# Image rotation trouble

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a picture and I'm trying to move it and rotate it. Moving works fine with this code

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbShowFormPlayPauseArrow" >
            <ThicknessAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                From="280,0,0,-420" To="280,0,0,400" 
                DecelerationRatio=".2" 
                Duration="0:0:1.35" />
        </Storyboard>
```

Rotation did like this

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="sbShowFormPlayPauseArrowRotate" >
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                From="0" To="180" 
                DecelerationRatio=".2" 
                Duration="0:0:1.35" />
        </Storyboard>
```

The animation call itself

```
private void RotateImage(string Storyboard, System.Windows.Controls.Image image)
        {
            Storyboard sb = Resources[Storyboard] as Storyboard;
            sb.Begin(image);
        }
RotateImage("sbShowFormPlayPauseArrow", arrowUp);
RotateImage("sbShowFormPlayPauseArrowRotate", arrowUp);
```

The project starts and does not produce any errors, only the image is moved, but there is no rotation
What's my mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your image (which xaml you did not provide) does not have `RenderTransform` set to `RotateTransform`, you need to do it like this:

```
<Image Source="...">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

The reason is you reference that `RotateTransform` from animation:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
```